# Debug: weird issue when state change

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I had a weird issue.

when I run **Nav.test.js**, **fakeCountryCollection** was also
changed inside **describe('something else')**, why is that?

**I couldn't figure out where I changed fakeCountryCollection.**

**Nav.js**

```
//clickNavDropdown will inverse showSubNav inside the state('countryCollection');

clickNavDropdown(countryCounter){
    let countryCollection = this.state.countryCollection;
    countryCollection[countryCounter].showSubNav = !countryCollection[countryCounter].showSubNav;

    this.setState({'countryCollection':countryCollection});
}
```

**Nav.test.js**

```
describe('test nav.js', function () {

    let fakeCountryCollection = [{value: 'england', count: 2, showSubNav: true},
        {value: 'canada', count: 0, showSubNav: false},
        {value: 'thailand', count: 0, showSubNav: true},
        {value: 'hongkon', count: 0, showSubNav: true}];


//clickNavDropdown will inverse showSubNav inside the state('countryCollection'). 
    describe('function clickNavDropdown', function () {
        let app = shallow(<Nav/>);
        app.setState({'countryCollection': fakeCountryCollection});
        let countryCollection = app.state('countryCollection');

        for (let [index, eachCollection] of countryCollection.entries()) {       

            app.instance().clickNavDropdown(index);
            it('iterator the countryCollection in: '+index, function () {
                ...
            });
        }
    });

    describe('something else', function () {
        console.log('fakeCountryCollection been inverse:  ',fakeCountryCollection);
        ...
    });
});
```

**Following shows in terminal:**

```
 fakeCountryCollection been inverse:   
      [ 
           { value: 'england', count: 2,showSubNav: false },
           { value: 'canada', count: 0, showSubNav: true },
           { value: 'thailand', count: 0, showSubNav: false },
           { value: 'hongkon', count: 0, showSubNav: false }
      ]
```

Comment: Hi @jimmy, can you please [rewrite your post to use normal formatting](/help/formatting), with code in code blocks, and text as normal text blocks, instead of right now having no regular text that talks us through your problem at all?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Ok I did it.

Comment: @jimmy I still don't get your question, what is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  I couldn't figure out where I change fakeCountryCollection.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete, so it's a good idea to start trying to great a [mcve]. Usually, while trying to get the code reduced, you end up finding the problem yourself, but if you don't you will have an excellent small set of code for putting in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, because the code snippet of Nav.test.js has ommissions, but it appears you are mutating fakeCountryCollection.

Declare it as a const and if there is an error it should tell you where you are making the unwanted mutation.